# How do i know if i am putting the right variable in loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem I am having is that when I run this code, the numbers printed out will keep printing non stop till the thousands.

```
weight = 43
height = 1.6**2
bmi = weight/height
while (bmi<18):
    print(weight)
    weight = weight+0.1
```

The results that I expected was that the weight will keep increasing by 0.1 until the bmi is just less than 18.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.  Also, you aren't updating your ```bmi``` variable within the loop so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: `bmi` never changes in the loop. Changing `weight` does not have any automatic effect on `bmi`. You need to recalculate `bmi` inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recalculate the BMI value after entering the loop or else your BMI value doesn't change and then you run into an infinite loop.

```py
weight = 43
height = 1.6**2
bmi = weight/height
while (bmi<18):
    print(weight)
    weight = weight+0.1
    bmi = weight/height
```